# Benchmarks for C compiler optimization

Tags: c, benchmarking, compiler-optimization

What are the standard benchmarks for comparing C the optimizer of various C compilers?

I'm particularly interested in benchmarks for ARM (or those that can be ported to ARM).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPECint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPECint is mostly written in C, and is the industry standard benchmark for real hardware, computer-architecture theoretical research (e.g. a larger ROB or some cache difference in a simulated CPU), and for compiler developers to test proposed patches that change code-gen.

The C parts of SPECfp (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPECfp) are also good choices.  Or for a compiler back-end optimizer, the choice of front-end language isn't very significant.  The Fortran programs are fine too.

---

Related:  [Tricks of a Spec master](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/summit2010?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=meissner2.pdf) is a paper that covers the different benchmarks.  Maybe originally from a conference.

> In this lightning round talk, I will
>   cover at a high level the performance characteristics of
>   these benchmarks in terms of optimizations that GCC
>   does. For example, some benchmarks are classic floating point applications and benefit from SIMD (single instruction multiple data) instructions, while other benchmarks don’t.

---

Wikipedia is out of date.  SPECint/fp 2017 was a long time coming, but it was released in 2017 and is a significant improvement over 2006.  e.g. some benchmarks trivialized by clever compiler optimizations like loop inversion.  (Some compilers over the years have added basically pattern-recognition to optimize the loop in libquantum, but they can't always do that in general for other loops even when it would be safe.  Apparently it can also be easily auto-parallelized.)

For testing a compiler, you might actually *want* code that aggressive optimization can find major simplifications in, so SPECcpu 2006 is a good choice.  Just be aware of the issues with libquantum.

https://www.anandtech.com/show/10353/investigating-cavium-thunderx-48-arm-cores/12 describes gcc as a compiler that "does not try to "break" benchmarks (libquantum...)".  But compilers like ICC and SunCC that CPU vendors use / used for SPEC submissions for their own hardware (Intel x86 and Sun UltraSPARC and later x86) are as aggressive as possible on SPEC benchmarks.

SPEC result submissions are required to include compiler version and options used (and OS tuning options), so you can hopefully replicate them.